# Django nested QuerySet yielding nothing

Tags: django

I am using Django 1.8 with Postgres 9.2 on a Windows 8 machine.

I have two pieces of nearly identical code from two of my projects.  One works and the other doesn't.

Here's the code that works:

```
# views.py

from django.shortcuts import render

from models import Artist, Track

def music(request):
    artists = Artist.objects.all().order_by('orderName')

    artistTrackCollections = []
    for artist in artists:
        artist.tracks = Track.objects.filter(artist=artist).order_by('order')
        artistTrackCollections.append(artist)

    return render(request, 'music.html', {'artistTrackCollections': artistTrackCollections,})
```

And the relevant template code:

```
{% for artist in artistTrackCollections %}
<dl>
    <dt>
    {% if artist.website %}
        <h2><a href="{{ artist.website }}">{{ artist.name }}</a></h2>
    {% else %}
        <h2>{{ artist.name }}</h2>
    {% endif %}
    </dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
        {% for track in artist.tracks %}
            <li>&ldquo;{{ track.title }}&rdquo;
                <i>({{ track.album.title }})</i>

        {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
{% endfor %}
```

Now here's pretty much the exact same code from a different project of mine that doesn't work anymore:

```
def index(request):
    productList = PartModel.objects.filter(isBuild=True, isActive=True).order_by('name')

    productCollection = []
    for product in productList:
        product.part_list = product.buildpart.all().order_by('family__type')[:5]
        productCollection.append(product)

    return render(request, 'index.html', { 'productCollection': productCollection, })
```

and its corresponding template:

```
{% for product in productCollection %}
    <p><a href="{{ product.get_absolute_url }}">{{ product.name }}</a>
    <p>${{ product.price }}
                <ul>
                {% for part in product.part_list %}
                    <li>{{ part.family.type.name }} | {{ part.name }}
                {% endfor %}
                </ul>
    {% endfor %}
```

This code used to work but now it doesn't.  In the code that works I succeed in going through each artist and attaching that artist's tracks.  In the code that fails I try to go through each PartModel instance that is a build and get that PartModel instance's corresponding parts.  They are identical as far as I can tell.  productCollection gets populated but the part_list data for some reason is blank.  This leads me to believe the problem is with this line:

```
product.part_list = product.buildpart.all().order_by('family__type')[:5]
```

But I cannot discern the difference from this line:

```
artist.tracks = Track.objects.filter(artist=artist).order_by('order')
```

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Some questions: 1) What is it supposed to render, and what does it render instead? 2) Have you tried running parts of Python code in `manage.py shell`, and checking if productList is non-empty, if the part-list you're generating contains what you want, etc?

Comment: Instead of assigning a new field to every instance, it might be easier to add the generated list as [a model method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/db/models/#model-methods), to avoid modifying the instances, and be able to share the code in other places.

Comment: There's not enough information here. What do the Product, BuildPart and Family models look like? It should be clear to you at least that your second bit of code is doing an extra join - from BuildPart to Family - when ordering, so the likelihood is that that join is the culprit. Are you sure that all buildparts have a family?

Comment: you ought to make this a property on your model instead of doing it in the view `product.part_list = product.buildpart.all().order_by('family__type')[:5]` (I think this is the same as what @che is saying)

Comment: also there is no point taking the queryset and manually adding all the items from it into a list (your `productCollection`) ...you could just pass the `productList` queryset into the template